# Make submenu appear under parent (center drop down menu)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have some problem with my horisontal drop down menu. The sub_menu is not appearing under its parent. Can anyone help me get it right? What am I doing wrong? I want the menu to be 100% wide and centerd.

```css
nav {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li:hover .sub_menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="#">link 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="#">link 3.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two steps**

*1. Set `position: relative;` for `li`:*

```
nav > ul > li {
padding: 10px;
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
```

*2. Set `right: 0;` for `ul`:*

```
.sub_menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyncvLp2/)**