# Centering of dropdown-menu submenus

Tags: css

I was adapting a `css` stylesheet for a dropdown-menu. I am having troubles with centering the boxes for the sub-menu. It currently looks like [image: this]

```
#nav{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:120px 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
}
#nav a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
#nav ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav ul li{
  display:block;
}
#nav li:hover ul{
  left:0;
}
#nav li:hover a{
}
#nav li:hover ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
  background:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul a:hover{
  background:#fff;
}
#nav ul a{
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:block;
}
a{
  color:#c00;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover{
}
```

But I would like that the sub-boxes are centered with respect to the box on the higher level. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675837/make-submenu-appear-under-parent-center-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make immediate (top level) `li`s into relative containers
- Left position nested `ul`s 50% within the newly-defined relative container and translate them `-50%` of their own size
- Remove `left:-9999px;` on nested `ul`s and toggle `display:` `none`/`block`

```css
#nav > li {
  position: relative;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

#nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#nav ul li {
  display: block;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#nav li:hover a {}

#nav li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

#nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: #c00;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">One</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6ktn34o/1/)